# Is it possible for macro to identify email from open attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to write a macro in excel.
When I send this xlsm file in email attachment
Receiver will open the attachment
Click on approve button in xlsm file.
Now after clicking approve, the original email should be forwarded to sender with "Approved" written

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried following code. But it forwards reply to any email which is currently selected in outlook. I need code where macro can identify email based on open attachment where receiver clicks "approved"

Comment: Dim outForward as Oulook.Mailitem.....
Set outForward = ActiveExplorer. Selection. Item(1).Forward.....
outForward. Receipents. add "abc@xyz.com"....
outForward.Send

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no link. When an attachment is opened, Outlook creates a file in the temp folder. That file will be deleted when Outlook thinks you are done with it.

You can make an assumption that the parent email is still displayed `(Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem`) or is selected (`Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)`), but, in general, that assumption will never be 100% true.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of cons of running macro enabled excel files on the recipient side. The solution may not work simply if VBA macros are disabled in the opened document. Most probably the attached file will be opened in [the protected mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653) where macros are disabled.

> Files from the Internet and from other potentially unsafe locations can contain viruses, worms, or other kinds of malware that can harm your computer. To help protect your computer, files from these potentially unsafe locations are opened as read only or in Protected View. By using Protected View, you can read a file and see its contents and enable editing while reducing the risks.

I'd suggest developing an Outlook add-in instead where you may handle incoming emails as you need. There also you can provide options for displaying the attached file and approving it. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) for more information.